# Генерация имен объектов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qtablewidget

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в качестве параметра в конструктор передавать имя объекта и в дальнейшем работать или с объектом `self.tableWidget` или `self.tableWidget_2`.

```
...

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self) # на форме есть два виджета: tableWidget и tableWidget_2

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим четыре варианта запуска программы:

1. `tableWidget-tableWidget_2.py`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. `tableWidget-tableWidget_2.py tableWidget`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. `tableWidget-tableWidget_2.py tableWidget_2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. `tableWidget-tableWidget_2.py blablabla`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`tableWidget-tableWidget_2.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5           import uic

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, form, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self) #на форме есть виджет tableWidget и tableWidget_2

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()

        if form == "tableWidget":
            layoutH.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        elif form == "tableWidget_2":
            layoutH.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2)
        else:
            layoutH.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
            layoutH.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2)

        centerWidget = QWidget()
        centerWidget.setLayout(layoutH) 
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)        


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:   # нет аргумента `имя объекта`
        print(__doc__)
        arg = "0"
    else:
        arg = sys.argv[1]    

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWindow(arg)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`form.ui`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>tableWidget и tableWidget_2</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>256</width>
      <height>192</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>tableWidget</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>440</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>256</width>
      <height>192</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>tableWidget_2</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то - имена не генеряться